# Gadgetfs - Filesystem not found

Tags: usb, gadget

While trying the solutions suggested by a comment on my [first question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104202/usb-hid-api-on-rpi-zero-pro-controller-emulation-on-the-rpi) I tried to enable gadgetfs. I tried the following:

```
sudo modprobe dwc2
sudo modprobe gadgetfs
sudo mkdir /dev/gadget
sudo mount -t gadgetfs none /dev/gadget
```

But while executing the `mount`-Command, following error occurs:
`mount: /dev/gadget: unknown filesystem type 'gadgetfs'.`

Does anyone know why this happens?

EDIT:

Output of `lsmod | grep gadget`:

```
gadgetfs               24576  0
udc_core               49152  4 dwc2,libcomposite,gadgetfs,usb_f_hid
```

`dmesg` containing dwc2 or gadget:

```
...
[    5.102521] dwc2 20980000.usb: 20980000.usb supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.102690] dwc2 20980000.usb: Linked as a consumer to regulator.0
[    5.102716] dwc2 20980000.usb: 20980000.usb supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.323744] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter lpm=1
[    5.326750] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter lpm_clock_gating=1
[    5.332324] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter besl=1
[    5.335372] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter hird_threshold_en=1
[    5.423716] dwc2 20980000.usb: EPs: 8, dedicated fifos, 4080 entries in SPRAM
[    5.425129] dwc2 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    5.425199] dwc2 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    5.425277] dwc2 20980000.usb: irq 33, io mem 0x20980000
...
[   34.182486] dwc2 20980000.usb: bound driver configfs-gadget
[  171.860961] gadgetfs: USB Gadget filesystem, version 24 Aug 2004
```

Comment: Can you check the output of `lsmod | grep gadget`? Also try reading through the output of `dmesg` for anything to do with dwc2 or gadget.

Comment: @Fred I've edited both in.

Comment: @Fred Any more hints?

Comment: I don't have any in-depth experience with gadgetfs so I'm a bit limited on what I can do. It looks like you may need to have a gadget module loaded before trying to mount. What happens if you try after `modprobe g_mass_storage`?

Comment: @Fred Still doesn't find "filesystem type 'gadgetfs'.".

Answer (score 2):

From [Pi Zero as HID: How to control PC Mouse from Pi Zero through USB?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56152/pi-zero-as-hid-how-to-control-pc-mouse-from-pi-zero-through-usb) and [Zero GadgetFS?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=152801), it looks like you must add `dtoverlay=dwc2` into `/boot/config.txt` and then restart.

Edit: @The Great Rambler below suggets that the libcomposite kernel module shouldn't be loaded. Based on searching for libcomposite, it also looks like these posts on [Composite Gadgets on Pi Zero](https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383) and [Pi Zero as Multiple Gadgets](http://irq5.io/2016/12/22/raspberry-pi-zero-as-multiple-usb-gadgets/) might be useful resources for using the Pi Zero in gadget mode.

Comment: In the config.txt there was that line two times at the end. Even when I removed one of them, restarted and tried again it failed.

Comment: Along with Fred's answer, make sure you don't have the kernel module `libcomposite` loaded.