# Raspberry Pi 400 as external keyboard via USB

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, otg, usb-c

Is it possible to use the raspberry pi 400 as an external keyboard on another PC or tablet using the USB-C (OTG) feature?

Comment: Going by https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=290760 the 400 does support OTG but it could be a cabling / power mess - I would rather use VNC to remote into the PC :-) Keyboard emulators (search HID keyboard Pi Zero) are all over the net for the Pi Zero - you would need to test it and handle keyboard entry / keyboard translation.  Very expensive way to replace a £5 basic keyboard (unless you are doing key logging / injection attacks) and even then there are cheaper ways.

Comment: Should be the same procedure as for the Pi Zero: [Pi Zero as HID: How to control PC Mouse from Pi Zero through USB?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56152/pi-zero-as-hid-how-to-control-pc-mouse-from-pi-zero-through-usb)

Comment: @Andyroo thanks for the advice using VNC! Did not think of this alternative. Will try as well. I already have 10 keyboards laying around my desk and it was just a way to quickly connect an existing Pi 400 to another PI.

Comment: @MisterGin Would this help https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/share-your-keyboard-and-mouse-between-computers-with-barrier/ I've not tried it but reads OK.  Now if they had an iPad version I'd be happy...